# serve static content from apache server to tomcat

Tags: apache-2.4, tomcat7

On my `index.html` page I have `<img src="static_content/asf_logo.png">`. I put the image into `Apache24/htdocs/static_content`.

I configured `httpd.conf` to have an acess to `localhost/basic-application-web`.

```
LoadModule jk_module modules/mod_jk.so
JkWorkersFile conf/workers.properties
JkMount /basic-application-web/* worker1
```

I can access it fine however it does not display the image.

`http://localhost/basic-application-web/static_content/asf_logo.png`

Return 404. How to provide image to the page?

I was trying to do like this

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot htdocs/
    <Directory htdocs>
        Options +Indexes
        AllowOverride None
        Allow from all
    </Directory>
    JkMount /basic-application-web/* worker1
</VirtualHost>
```

But it changed nothing

Answer (score 0):

Since the `JkMount` directive you have forwards the whole `/basic-application-web` directory to Tomcat, when a request is made for the static image URL, it will be forwarded to Tomcat, thus you get a 404.

You need to unmount the static content directory from mod_jk, by adding the following line after the `JkMount ...` line:

```
JkUnMount /basic-application-web/static-content/* worker1
```

Answer (score 0):

I resolved the issue like this. In `httpd.conf` I left only these lines

```
LoadModule jk_module modules/mod_jk.so
JkWorkersFile conf/workers.properties
```

`VirtualHost` past started to look like this

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "${SRVROOT}/htdocs"
    <Directory "${SRVROOT}/htdocs/static_content">
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride None
        Require all granted
    </Directory>
    JkMount /basic-application-web/ worker1
</VirtualHost>
```

Additionally I adjusted `html` page with path to image by adding aditional `/` before image path

```
<img src="/static_content/asf_logo.png">
```